# Ошибка Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! при сборке APK в Qt

Tags: android, qt, ant

Когда собираю любое Qt приложение под Android, выводятся такие ошибки:

`16:29:31: Выполняются этапы для проекта untitled3...
16:29:31: Настройки не изменились, этап qmake пропускается.
16:29:31: Запускается: «/usr/bin/make» 
make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
16:29:31: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился успешно.
16:29:31: Удаление каталога /home/homa/build-untitled3-Android_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_8_0-Debug/android-build
16:29:31: Запускается: «/usr/bin/make» INSTALL_ROOT=/home/homa/build-untitled3-Android_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_8_0-Debug/android-build install
install -m 755 -p libuntitled3.so /home/homa/build-untitled3-Android_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_8_0-Debug/android-build/libs/armeabi-v7a/libuntitled3.so
16:29:31: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился успешно.
16:29:31: Запускается: «/home/homa/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt» --input /home/homa/build-untitled3-Android_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_8_0-Debug/android-libuntitled3.so-deployment-settings.json --output /home/homa/build-untitled3-Android_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_8_0-Debug/android-build --deployment bundled --android-platform android-25 --jdk /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 --ant /home/homa/Android/apache-ant-1.10.1/bin/ant
Generating Android Package
  Input file: /home/homa/build-untitled3-Android_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_8_0-Debug/android-libuntitled3.so-deployment-settings.json
  Output directory: /home/homa/build-untitled3-Android_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_8_0-Debug/android-build/
  Application binary: /home/homa/build-untitled3-Android_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_8_0-Debug/libuntitled3.so
  Android build platform: android-25
  Install to device: No
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
16:29:31: Процесс «/home/homa/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt» завершился с кодом 14.
Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта untitled3 (комплект: Android для armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.8.0) )
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка Android APK»
16:29:31: Прошло времени: 00:01.`

SDK, NDK, JDK и Ant установил. Пути в QtCreator'е прописаны так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`~ $ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.1 compiled on February 2 2017
~ $ echo $ANT_HOME
/home/homa/Android/apache-ant-1.10.1
~ $ echo $PATH
/home/homa/bin:/home/homa/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/homa/Android/apache-ant-1.10.1/bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было откатить к старой (25.2.5) версии SDK tools.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-17852

Comment: Ну или использовать Qt 5.9 и выше с SDK tools 25.3.0 и выше, но тогда надо вместо Ant использовать Grandle.